# Left Join tables in python where the number of input tables can change each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, left-join

I have a need where the **number of tables to be merged can change each time as per the data availability**. For example below sometimes it can be all the 3 (df1, df2, df3) or any two (df1,df2 or df2,df3 or df1, df3) or a single. The *join key* in all is **'name'** and the *type of join* is **left**.

I don't want the end user to input the table names manually but rather have a function which can do it depending on the available data from previous steps dynamically and skip the dataframes which are not available.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12']) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        ['a', 5, 19],
        ['b', 14, 16],
        ['c', 4, 9]]),
        columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22']) 

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        ['a', 15, 49],
        ['b', 4, 36],
        ['c', 14, 9]]),
        columns=['name', 'attr31', 'attr32'])
```

Can this be done by left join using try & except?

Answer (score 0):

One way I found out to do a dynamic merging is create a empty dataframe with Schema for each table:

**Example for df1**

```
#Creates Empty RDD
emptyRDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
  StructField('name', StringType(), True),
  StructField('attr11', DoubleType(), True),
  StructField('attr11', LongType(), True)
  ])

#Create the dataset even if not used
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD, schema)
```

Then pass it to the join function . So, even when there is no data an empty dataframe will get merged. We only have to delete the columns which have all null values and final output is ready.